# Codeigniter Ajax Login Shows Same Multiple Errors If Submit More Than Once And Error Found

Tags: codeigniter

Currently I am submitting form by ajax

But when there is a validation error and it shows up fine but if I click it a second time multuple errors show. It repets the errors for some reason.

Question: How is it possiable to stop the same error message from showing up multiple times if there is a error on form each time I submit.

Image

[image]

Controller

```
<?php

class Login extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['refresh'] = current_url();

        $this->load->view('default/template/members/login_view', $data);
    }

    public function validate() {

        $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"','</p>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $data['messages'] = validation_errors('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');

        } else {

            $data['success'] = true;

            echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

View

```
<form id="form-login" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div id="error"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><b>Username/Email</b></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" />
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><b>Password</b></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#close').on('click', function(e) {
        location.reload();
    });

    $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('catalog/members/login/validate');?>",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success == true) {

                } else {

                    $( "#error" ).append(response.messages);
                }
            }
        });

    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: The reason it is doing that is because you are telling it to by using .append(response.messages). Append means to add to what is already there... Try using .html(response.messages) which should overwrite it each time.

Comment: Yep easy fix cheers.